# input type file not showing all the selected files

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am having one event creation page which has multiple file upload option. here they select the all images at a time or they can load the files one by one like that.

Now the problem is, when I open file select dialog another time, the previously selected files got removed from the file input.

How to resolve this?

Html.erb

```
<div class="uploads">
  <span id="media" class="row gallery attachment_gallery">
  </span>
  <div class="file_upload">
    <label for="event_file" ><%= image_tag('upload.png', class: "upload_img figure-img img-fluid") %></label>
      <%= f.file_field :media, multiple: true, id: "event_file", hidden: true %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Js script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#event_file").on("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
          var file = e.target;
          $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
            "<br/><span class=\"remove\">X</span>" +
            "</span>").appendTo(".attachment_gallery");
          $(".remove").click(function(){
            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
          });
        });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]